# Can Non-Muslim read Qur'an without wudu?

Tags: quran, non-muslim, quran-recitation

A friend told me that non-believers are prohibited from touching the Qur'an. I'm only 15 and my family is originally a Hindu, but I don't think my parents will mind me reading the Qur'an. Also I am not too sure about converting because I only want to take in the messages of the Qur'an, as I think it has information to leading a better life. And converting while living at home will be difficult, because my Mum is a devoted Hindu. Would I be able to read the Qur'an? I really really want to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone can read the Quran.

As Muslims, indeed we believe that we should only touch the Quran while pure, but we cannot prevent anyone from touching it. In fact giving the Quran to non-muslims and allowing them to read it is what can bring them closer to Islam, so why should we prevent them? It wouldn't make any sense to basically prevent people from learning about Islam.

So go on, read the Quran as you please, you will definitely not regret it.

Comment: Please learn [how to answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) 
in order to make it a damn cool answer or if you wish to continue to contribute more to this site. Plz take some time for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The prophet PBUH said:

> (لا يمس القرآن إلا طاهر)

No one touches the Quran except if you are clean. We all also know of the Hadith where Omar's sister asked him to make Wudu before reading the reading the Quran when he was a non-muslim.

Many scholars take this hadith and many others as saying that if the Person is isn't clean and say it is OK if the Quran is in Digital/Audio format (since it is not in writing).

There was a Minority of scholars that said it is OK to read the Quran when you are dirty or during a woman's period. This is something that I personally tend to agree with based from my understanding.

Sources:

- http://islamqa.info/ar/106961
- https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/12540

Answer (score 0):

As and always, there might be **some** problem with Non Muslims touching the physical Qur'an as as others have said that it has to be touched only by the [purified,](http://quran.com/56/77-79) and also, from [Can Muslims allow non-muslims to touch mushaf?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/can-muslims-allow-non-muslims-to-touch-mushaf), we infer that as long as you respect it you're free to use it.

Although, whether Non-Muslims can touch or not is unclear, but, as far as I know, reading without disrespecting it, is completely fine. After all, that is the main purpose of Qur'an, it came down [give guidance](http://quran.com/50/45) to the mankind.

But as a piece of advice, just washing with water your hands, face etc. with an intention to touch a Holy Book would be much appreciated & preferred.

May the creator guide us all.

---

<sub>**Note:** The verse linked to the first part i.e. Qur'an 56:79 is talking about Angels. But still, some believe it is applicable on humans touching the physical Qur'an too.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

yes you can as long as you are not in a major impurity. just bath yourself to make sure you are clean thats all. and if you are too lazy to even bath just put a clean glows in your hand in which case you are not physically touching quran (that glows thing is not said by any scholars but me, but as i said you are not touching quran you are just touching the CLEAN glows and the glows is touching the quran).

Answer (score -3):

When Muslims want to read the Quran, they get wudu  to touch the Arabic words of the Quran  because according of following verse   only the people who are clean or purify can touch the  Arabic Quran text:

> his is indeed a Holy Quran, in a book well-guarded, which none shall
>   touch but those who are clean.." (56:77-79)

If you do not touch the Qur’anic verse by your hands, you can read the Quran without any cleanness

Comment: The verse you mentioned is in context of angels. It does not tell what we should do before reading it

Comment: @goto any proof for your statement? This verse is often used as a proof for the need of purity to touch a Quran. And angels are pure "by default"...