# What if a non Muslim asks for the Quran?

Tags: quran, fiqh, non-muslim

I am traveling in a train a non Muslim is sitting in front of me ,I tell him about Islam and he asks me for the Quran and he is napak( can not touch the Quran) so what should I do at that time because there is a hope that he may convert to Islam if I help him.

Comment: This requires some clarification: Are you talking about the qur'an (only Arabic copy, nothing else) or a translation or tafsir etc.?

Comment: Translation with Arabic

Answer (score 0):

Only the qur'anic text (Arabic - only and without any additions) has certainly the ruling of purity which all other posts require:

> None touch it except the purified. ([56:79](https://legacy.quran.com/56/79))

And this text which is written or printed in hardcover is stirctly speaking a moshaf not the qur'an!

There's basically nothing hindering you from reaching out a printed copy of the qur'an including a translation or any kind of different text (like tafssir).
It might be better to avoid this if possible as the matter might still be a controversial topic among scholars. You may share a pure translation or translation of the meanings of the qur'an instead. However in that case you should be as certain as possible that this translation is one approved and accepted by Muslims.

For further information refer to:
[Are non-Muslims allowed to touch an English translation of the Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13387/are-non-muslims-allowed-to-touch-an-english-translation-of-the-quran)
[Can Muslims allow non-Muslims to touch mushaf?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/can-muslims-allow-non-muslims-to-touch-mushaf)
[Can we complete quran by reading from book and then from device](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24815/can-we-complete-quran-by-reading-from-book-and-then-from-device)